# Need File Input Element cloned from 1 form into another via PHP & Javascript

Tags: forms, upload, clone, element, file-io

Ok, I have an  in template function that get's submitted via method="POST".  But I can't submit this normally, since this is all I want submitted, and there is already a  tag defined above the code and than below the code, closing the form with  that must remain there.  Since, there is no way to have forms inside of forms, I am using Javascript to create a form and submit it on the fly.  But I need to get a copy of the file input element defined in the document.forms.creator form.  I am using PHP and Javascript to accomplish what I have now, but the cloneNode(true) isn't getting the $_FILES['image'] array and setting it to the $_FILES['sigImg'] array :(

```
echo '<tr><td colspan="2"><a href="#" name="sig' . $user_info['id'] . '"></a><center><b>Signature Image Rotator</b></center><br /><center>
Add Image: <input type="file" size="48" id="imagefile" name="image" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="createFormAndSubmit()"></center>';


echo '
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"><!-- // --><![CDATA[
//helper function to create the form
function getNewSubmitForm(){
 var submitForm = document.createElement("FORM");
 document.body.appendChild(submitForm);
 submitForm.enctype = "multipart/form-data";
 submitForm.method = "POST";
 return submitForm;
}

//function that creates the form, clones <input type="file" name="image">,
//and then submits it
function createFormAndSubmit(){
 var submitForm = getNewSubmitForm();
 var element = document.getElementById("imagefile");
    element = element.cloneNode(true);
    element.id = \'sigImgId\'; //<- ID Assignment
    element.name = \'sigImg\'; //<- NAME Assignment
    submitForm.appendChild(element);
 submitForm.action= "', $scripturl, '?action=sigimages;sa=upload";
 submitForm.submit();
}
// ]]></script></td></tr>';
```

How can I get a real clone of the file input defined in the php echo and place it into the form defined in the createFormAndSubmit() function??

Please, somebody help...

Comment: Just to make sure i am understanding correctly, you are wanting to post a files to the server in a popup, but still reference that file from the original window's form?  If so, would simply have the child/iframe be the post target, then have that return a script to append an id into a hidden field, and the filename in your main form.

Comment: No, do not want a popup.  Just want to clone the <input type="file" size="48" id="imagefile" name="image" /> within the createFormAndSubmit() function and change the name and id to:  name="sigImg" id="sigImgId" and when submitForm.submit(); get's called, sigImg should have set the $_FILES['sigImg'] from the image file input.

Comment: an iframe will not work since after the action is performed it takes them right back to the page they were on.  There has got to be a way to clone a file input element so that when the cloned element gets submitted, it has set the $_FILES from the original.  I need this in order to be able to check file size, mime type, etc.

Comment: This guy Mark Allen wrote on a way to do this here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415483/clone-a-file-input-element-in-javascript/528996#528996
But I can't understand how I can integrate that code into mine... Any Ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks a lot Chris, will definitely keep this in mind.  Had just figured out a way to fix this myself and am using this method which just changes the form's action and submits, only problem it submits everything in the form instead of just the imagefile object.  But I guess that's not really a problem, or is it?  Anyways works with this code:

```
// change the action and submit the form...
function submitSigImg(){
 var mainForm = document.forms.creator;
 mainForm.action= "', $scripturl, '?action=sigimages;sa=upload";
 mainForm.submit();
}
```

This just changes the action of the form it is already in and since this function only gets used on clicking of the upload button and redirects back to the page, it isn't a problem when submitting the form normally either.

Thanks Again :)

Answer (score 0):

The Mark Allen comment on the other thread is suggesting that instead of appending your new cloned input (which IE doesn't give the selected file property) to the other form, you replace the old input with the new input (which looks proper), and then you put the old input on your upload form.

So your code would become:

```
// clone up a new one
var oldFile = document.getElementById("imagefile");
var newFile = oldFile.cloneNode(true);

// set props
newFile.id = "sigImgId"; //<- ID Assignment
newFile.name = "sigImg"; //<- NAME Assignment

// replace old with new
oldFile.parentNode.replaceChild(newFile, oldFile);

// attach old to upload form
submitForm.appendChild(oldFile);
```