# How clone value input file

Tags: jquery, file, input

How I can clone value attribute of file input field.
Something like this:

```
<input type="file" id="field1"/>
<input type="file" id="field2"/>
<script>
$('#field2').val($('#field1').val());
</script>
```

Comment: that looks like it should work, whats the issue?

Comment: Were you hoping to access the full path of the file selected by the user? If so, I'm pretty sure you won't be able to.

Comment: [Exception... "Security error" code: "1000" nsresult: "0x805303e8 (NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR)" location: "http://local/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js Line: 2"] { constructor=DOMException, filename="http://local/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js", code=1000, more...}

Comment: I have two forms one is facade second is real. When click over field1 must copy value to field2

Comment: It looks like direct cloning is only possible in Firefox ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JgXVN/)), but MarkAllen's answer here might be a solution for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415483/clone-a-file-input-element-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found solution of this problem:

```
<input type="file" id="field1"/>
<span id="field2_area"><input type="file" id="field2"/></span>
<script>
$('#field1').change(function(){
    var clone = $(this).clone();
    clone.attr('id', 'field2');
    $('#field2_area').html(clone);
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you please tell me where from "field1_area" comes.

Comment: <span id="field2_area"><input type="file" id="field2"/></span>

Comment: This does not work. It appears to clone, but when the form is submitted, the second file input is empty.

Comment: This is not working in the safari. Is there any way out for that?

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting them to stay the same when user interacts with them:

```
$(function(){
    $('#field1').on('keyup blur', function(){

            $('#field2').val($(this).val());

     }).blur();
});
```

Triggering the blur() on page load will do the same as code you already have

**EDIT**  Just realized these are file fields...  browser security limits what you can do with them