# How can i clone array of input type file?

Tags: javascript, html

I want solve this topic when i read [How clone value input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658361/how-clone-value-input-file)?

I have array of input type file

```
<input type="file" class = "focus_image" name="focus_image[]" >
```

and i want to clone value input type file of array to another input type file same below

```
<input type="file" class = "focus_image" name="clone[]">
```

I know this problem can solve with javascript but i can't implement Help me to solve this problem!

Edit
I have popup that user can add more image then user click button save in popup then popup close and i copy value input type array of file from popup to out scope popup(from focus_image to clone)

Comment: You want to create a new `input` field with `name="clone[]"`?

Comment: I guess no one even know what you want to do.

Comment: Tell us what you want to achieve. Including handling this file uploaded. Maybe you should copy this file after uploading to the server? Why do you want to upload the same file twice?

Comment: I have popup that user can add more image then user click button save in popup then popup close and i copy value input type array of file from popup to out scope popup

Comment: i want to clone value from focus_image to clone

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to get the element that you're concerned with. You may wish to use querySelectorAll, with the appropriate selector. Or you may do as I have, and jujst give the original input a unique id.

Next, you have to create a clone of the desired element.

Following this, you need to change the name and (if you've done as I have - giving it an id) the id.

Lastly, you need to append the clone to the DOM.

Something a little like this, perhaps?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function mInit()
{
    var elem = byId('origElemId');
    var copy = elem.cloneNode(true);

    copy.setAttribute('name', 'clone[]');
    copy.setAttribute('id', 'copyElemId');
    document.body.appendChild(copy);
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input id='origElemId' type="file" class = "focus_image" name="focus_image[]" >
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" class = "focus_image" name="focus_image[]" onChange="document.getElementById('cloned').value=this.value">

<input type="file" class = "focus_image" name="clone" id="cloned">
```

Answer (score 0):

//Hope so this will work for you
// Put this code in your Html Page

```
        <div id="form-content">
            <div id="cloned-content">
                <input type="file" class = "focus_image" name="focus_image[]" >                
            </div>
        </div>
    <a style="cursor: pointer" id="makeclone"> makeclone </a>
```

// This code will clone your all fields inside the div cloned-cotent

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
var cloneCounter = 1;
function makeClones() {
    // clone the div
    var clone = $("#cloned-content").clone(false);
    // change all id values to a new unique value by adding "_cloneX" to the end
    // where X is a number that increases each time you make a clone
    $("*", clone).add(clone).each(function() {
        if (this.id) {
            this.id = this.id + cloneCounter;
        }
        if (this.name) {
            this.name = this.name
        }
    });
    ++cloneCounter;
    $("#form-content").append(clone);                         

}

$("#makeclone").click(function() { 
    alert("Clicked Fired"); 
    makeClones();
});
```

});