# jquery clone input file was not adding file when clone div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Working on the jquery clone with the current code if I click add more button I am able to clone in  the original one i can able to attach the file but if I try to attach any file in the cloned one it is not working.

**I tried even replacing id with class but still it is not working**

Here is the jquery code

```
    var count=0;
    $(document).on("click", ".attch_add_button", function () {
        var $clone = $('.cloned-row4:eq(0)').clone(true,true);
        //$(".custom-file-input").closest('form').trigger('reset');
        //$(".custom-file-input").replaceWith('.check'.val('').clone(true));
        //alert("Clone number" + clone);
        $clone.find('[id]').each(function(){this.id+=''});
        $clone.find('.btn_more').after("<input type='button' class='btn_right btn_less1' id='buttonless'/>")
        $clone.attr('id', "added"+(++count));
        //$clone.find('#custom-file-input').val('');
        $clone.find('.preview').hide();
        $clone.wrap('<form>');
        $clone.closest('form').trigger('reset');
        $clone.unwrap();

        //$clone.find('input[type=file]').val('');

        //$clone.find('.pn_field').val("");
        $(this).parents('.medica_rpt').after($clone);
    });
```

Here is the fiddle [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/546udj15/10/)

Kindly suggest here

Comment: Click to the right of the 'Attach' button and you'll notice the `input` is misplaced. You would have to do a deep clone by the way to copy the event listeners.

Comment: hi thanks for the suggestion  I have tired  with true for the clone but not working can you please help me

Comment: hi kindly please suggest me

Comment: Seems to work alright when using `clone(true, true)`. Apart from the `input` itself being offset to the right from the button in the fiddle (seems to be in place when pasted in Codepen). I'd be very careful with any kind of file uploads by the way. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWaRzz

Comment: @hi thanks for the reply first time when the user click the attach button he can able to attach once when the user click the add more then he tries the attach button from the cloned div it was not working kindly please suggest me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89888/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-shikkediel).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/415483/3168107

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach unique events for each element, if you create a function that attaches the events to a received element the problem will be solved:

```
function addActions(container){

    var $preview = container.find(".preview");
    //var $acceptdiv = $("#accept_div");
    //$acceptdiv.hide();
    $preview.hide();

    container.find(".check").on("change", function(){
      alert("alert");
      var filename = this.value;
      var files = this.files;
      var URL = window.URL||window.webkitURL;
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
      $preview.attr("href", url);
      $preview.show();
      //$acceptdiv.show();
      container.find("#file_name").val(filename).prop("disabled", true);
    });

  }
```

I've modified your example:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/546udj15/11/)