# jQuery clone function is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

```js
$(function() {
  var m_row = 0;
  $("body").on("click", "#m_add", function() {
    console.log("click lagche");

    var result = "0";
    var row;
    row = '<tr id="row_' + m_row + '">';

    var clone = $("#m_input_file").clone();
    clone.attr('id', "");
    clone.attr('name', "m_input_file" + m_row);

    row += '<td id="file_' + m_row + '"></td>';
    row += '<td><input type="hidden" name="m_sl[]" value="' + m_row + '"></td>';
    row += '</tr>';
    $("#workmanship_check table tbody").prepend(row);
    console.log(clone);
    $("#file_" + m_row).html(clone);

    m_row++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="workmanship_check" >
    <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>
         <input type="file" id="m_input_file">
       </th>
       <th><a href="#" id="m_add">Add</a></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

It is working in Mozilla firefox Browser but not in Chrome.

Is there any way to work it?

If not please suggest how I can add input file dynamically with value?

https://jsfiddle.net/abid06/hwtmapc9/4/

Comment: by not working what do you mean by that?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: did you check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415483/clone-a-file-input-element-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

> how can i add input file dynamically with value

You can't, reliably. Browsers are really careful with file inputs, because they have such potential for security bugs. You can *move* a file element while retaining its value, but you can't clone it while retaining its value, not reliably across browsers, for much the same reason you can't create an element with a supplied default value.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.