# Variable becomes empty after resetting input field

Tags: jquery, input

```
<input type="file" onchange="uploadFiles()" multiple/>
```

After storing the input value in a variable and resetting the input field, the variable becomes empty

```
function uploadFiles(){
    var newFiles = $('input')[0].files;
    $('input').replaceWith($('input').val('').clone(true));
    console.log(newFiles); // result == []
}
```

Please how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('input')[0].files` gives you the [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileList) property of the `input`, which is attached to it. Changing the value of the input will result in changing the value of the property and all its assignments.

You can work around the problem by adding the files to a separate array:

```
var newFiles = $('input')[0].files;
var filesArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<newFiles.length; i++){
    filesArray[i] = newFiles[i];
}
$('input').replaceWith($('input').val('').clone(true));
console.log(newFiles); // result == []
console.log(filesArray); // result == [File]
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zohalexix/4covyham/1/)

*Note: For security reasons, you may or may not use the Files as intended after changing the value of the original input. I haven't tested it though. If you can confirm or debunk, please comment.*

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `onchange` event gets fired a second time when you reset the input field. Resetting the input field is considered a change.

A way around this would be to temporarily disable the `onchange` events while you update the value.

```
// remove the change handler
$('input').off('change', uploadFiles);
$('input').val('');
// re-establish the change handler
$('input').on('change', uploadFiles);
```

Note: it isn't a good idea to mix inline event handlers (`onchange="whatever"`) with handlers in your script. You should just jQuery `on()`.

Comment: Well spotted. I was about to close as duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415483/clone-a-file-input-element-in-javascript

Comment: He is resetting the value by calling `.val('')`, which doesn't trigger onchange automatically.

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin calling `.val()` isn't the issue, it's replacing the input that's considered the change.

Comment: So what's the best way to do that?

Comment: @Soviut, replacing an element doesn't trigger onchange either. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zohalexix/4covyham/

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin Please write an answer then.